# How to install NPM dependencies of a github action?

Tags: github-actions

I am setting up github actions, and struggling to see how to handle the dependencies of a particular action.

Below is a simplified view of my repository setup, with the action and workflow YAML files as I currently understand them.

**my-org/my-tool@master**: a specific tool in my organisation that I want to enable as a github action

- `package.json`
- `tool.js`: the tool, depending on npm packages described in `package.json`
- `action.yml`

```yaml
name: my-tool
inputs:
  file:
    description: file to be processed by my-tool
    required: true
runs:
  using: node16
  main: tool.js
```

**my-org/my-code@branch**: a code repository where I want to run the tool as an action

- `my-code.js`: some code that needs to be processed by the tool
- `.github/workflows/use-tool.yml`:

```yaml
# ...
jobs:
  tool:
    steps:
      - uses: my-org/my-tool@master
        with:
          file: my-code.js
    # ...
```

If `my-tool` has no dependencies, this setup works well enough. But `my-tool` needs to have dependencies installed to function properly, i.e., a single `npm install` in its root directory. **How do I specify this dependency in a github action setup?**

I have multiple options, none of which are truly satisfying to me:

1. I can define a workflow that checks out `my-tool`, installs the dependencies, and then runs it. However, I don't want that logic to be in the workflow yaml of the `my-code` repository, as I have multiple similar repositories, all of which require `my-tool`, which will result in duplication. I don't see how to do this in the `action.yml` file itself. It seems I have to choose between a javascript action to run node tools, or a composite action to run shell tools.
2. I can bundle the `node_modules` directory in the `my-tool` repository; this bloats my repos unnecessarily.
3. I can bundle an `ncc` distribution of `my-tool` in its repo; same problem.
4. I can define and build a container image of `my-tool` with its dependencies installed, and use a container action to run the tool on `my-code`. This seems like overhead to me, and I have no idea how this container would access the files from the `my-org/my-code` repo (which would be its core purpose).

Options 2 and 3 are the ones described in the [example published by github](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-javascript-action#commit-tag-and-push-your-action-to-github). I would be happy with using an *artifact* (either `node_modules` dir or `ncc` distribution) as the basis for an action, but there seems to be no way to do this.

My specific use case concerns npm dependencies, but there seems to be a generic use case for "action with dependencies", support for which is unclear to me from reading the documentation. I can't be the only dev in the world working with a toolset with dependencies of its own. Maybe I am looking at this setup in the wrong way. Is there a best practice for actions with dependencies? Is there a best practice to only have actions with zero dependencies?

I look forward to learn from any partial answer or suggestion.

Comment: The repo is the deployment mechanism for an action.  That means that the code needs to exist in your repo to run your action, so you’ll need to do 2 or 3, and we recommend 3.  What is your actual concern with this?  You say “bloats my repos” but what’s the _actual_ problem?  Time spent fetching your main (non deployment) branch?

Comment: The repo bloat itself is my concern; I prefer my repos to be purely source, not store derived artifacts. Pragmatism trumps principle of course, and your answer made me think: I can add a distribution branch specific to this action, where the ncc distribution is stored, and nobody ever needs to check this branch out; this makes the repo only bloated at github-side, not at at my side (or my colleagues'), which I think will be good enough. Thank you!

Comment: For those interested: @EdwardThomson has a blog post where he describes this practice of maintaining a separate branch for packaged actions: https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/building_an_action.html. Well written and broadly applicable, thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could install dependencies in pre action? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#pre